# Mixed content in com_content in Joomla 3.x

Tags: php, joomla

I have my page and the console shows error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://abcde.com/blog' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://abcde.com/?option=com_content&id=0&task=ajax&page=0&lang=pl-PL&extra_page_only=0'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I search in my com_content but there is no reference to http or https

```
 <a href="/index.php?option=com_content&id=<?php echo $this->id;?>&task=<?php echo $this->ajax;?>&page=<?php echo $this->next;?>&lang=<?php echo $this->lang;?>&extra_page_only=<?php echo $this->extra_page_only;?>">
```

Where should I search for answer? Where is it defined globally to change http:// into // ? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when you have an HTTPS redirect in your .htaccess file, but you have not modified your Joomla configuration settings to use HTTPS. As the previous answer stated, you can do that by going to the System -> Global Configuration page, and then clicking on the Server tab, and finally changing the value of "Force HTTPS" to "Entire Site".

Answer (score 0):

Log in to the back end of the website and set System -> Global Configuration -> Server -> Force HTTPS to "Entire Site".

Comment: if I do so, my whole page shows 404 error, too many redirects

Comment: You may have a redirection conflict in the `.htaccess` file or the live_site parameter in the `configuration.php` file or elsewhere.